# Flying to Germany from another country where the visa has been issued

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, australia, iran

I got my Schengen Visa for Germany in Australia, and I’m planing to visit in February. Is it going to be a problem if I fly to Germany from a country other than Australia?

I’m planing to visit my home country (Iran) and fly to Germany from there.

Comment: The border officers don't know from where you're arriving or which airplane you have arrived on (unless there was only one landed in the last 30 minutes).

Comment: They do know from where you have arrived since they have API (Advance Passenger Information) which airlines are obligated to send, but doing so has no impact on your visa validity or eligibility to enter Germany.

Answer (score 5):

No. You can fly to Germany from any non-Schengen country in the world. They might ask you about what you were doing in Iran, but as long as it wasn't crime/terror related, you should be fine.